# Folded distribution on the sphere

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $X$ is distributed on the real line with density $f_X$, then $|X|$ is distributed on $[0,\infty)$ with density $f_{|X|}(x) = f(x) + f(-x)$. This follows from differentiation of

$$F_{|X|}(x) = P(|X|\leq x) = P(-x\leq X\leq x) = F_X(x) - F_X(-x)$$

Similarly for $X$ distributed in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with density $f_X$, and $Y=(|X_1|,X_2,X_3)$, we have
$$f_{Y}(x_1,x_2,x_3) = f_X(x_1,x_2,x_3) + f(-x_1,x_2,x_3)$$

Suppose now, that $X=(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is distributed on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Can we express the density of $Y=(|X_1|,X_2,X_3)$ in terms of a density function of $X$? I don't see how do we show this in the similar fashion, since the sphere is curved and we can't clearly define probabilities of falling into cuboids in terms of CDFs, as we do for distributions on $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the general formula you gave for $f_Y$ still holds in this case: This is a consequence of the [change-of-variables formula for PDFs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables):

$$ f_{g(X)}(y) = \sum_{x\in g^{-1}(y)} \frac{f_X(x)}{|g'(x)|}. $$